# Expo build apk a lot of std errors

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, apk

I'm trying to build the apk using expo but I have all this errors and I don't know how to fix it! When i try to run the app with expo go there aren't amy problems but when I try to build the apk by the expo website BUM, it doesn't work...

[file download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ZChZDogyLLOUG20mE4zPDvW9Cbc1F1-/view?usp=sharing)